# Reachability added in static library

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, static-libraries, reachability

I have my Static Library
In this project i added a Reachability.h .m file.
So, I have some linker errors:
I added also the CFNetwork and System.Configuration framwork

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress", referenced from:
      +[Reachability reachabilityWithAddress:] in libAdvertisingPromotions.a(Reachability.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName", referenced from:
      +[Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:] in libAdvertisingPromotions.a(Reachability.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags", referenced from:
      -[Reachability connectionRequired] in libAdvertisingPromotions.a(Reachability.o)
      -[Reachability currentReachabilityStatus] in libAdvertisingPromotions.a(Reachability.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityScheduleWithRunLoop", referenced from:
      -[Reachability startNotifier] in libAdvertisingPromotions.a(Reachability.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback", referenced from:
      -[Reachability startNotifier] in libAdvertisingPromotions.a(Reachability.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityUnscheduleFromRunLoop", referenced from:
      -[Reachability stopNotifier] in libAdvertisingPromotions.a(Reachability.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this...
I added systemconfiguration.framework in my test app project that uses my static library

Comment: Is this the only way of fixing it though? Shouldn't you be able to include the systemconfiguration.framework in the static library rather than the app project?

Answer (score 0):

You must be sure, that your Reachability.h .m gets compiled. You need to go to your "Build Phases", then to "Compile SOurces" and add Reachability.m to compile sources.